# Phoenix server main index page not redirectly properly after session expire

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to elixir and phoenix, and this is my first project with it.

In my app, I implemented a simple username/password authentication with some routes requiring authenticated access.

Everything seems to go well, except when I take a break and started the development server again the next day. When I attempt to access the home page, the browser shows 'The page isn't redirecting properly'. So I opened up the dev tools and the dev server seems to be returning `302 Found` with `Location: /`, resulting in infinite redirect.

On the dev server terminal, the following error is shown on every request made (because of the redirect).

> `[error] Ranch listener DemoWeb.Endpoint.HTTP had connection process started with :cowboy_clear:start_link/4 at #PID<0.816.0> exit with reason: {:function_clause, [{:cowboy_http, :commands, [{:state, #PID<0.376.0>, DemoWeb.Endpoint.HTTP, #Port<0.105>, :ranch_tcp, :undefined, %{env: %{dispatch: [{:_, [], [{:_, [], Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler, {DemoWeb.Endpoint, []}}]}]}, stream_handlers: [:cowboy_telemetry_h, :cowboy_stream_h]}, "", %{}, {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 55044}, {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 4000}, :undefined, #Reference<0.1526777474.1731461121.208048>, true, 2, {:ps_request_line, 0}, 65535, 1, :done, 1000, [{:stream, 1, {:cowboy_telemetry_h, {:state, {:cowboy_stream_h, {:state, :undefined, DemoWeb.Endpoint.HTTP, #PID<0.817.0>, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, 0, :nofin, "", 0, ...}}, #Function<0.122385210/1 in :cowboy_telemetry_h."-fun.metrics_callback/1-">, :undefined, %{body_length: 0, cert: :undefined, has_body: false, headers: %{"accept" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", "accept-encoding" => "gzip, deflate", "accept-language" => "en-US,en;q=0.5", "connection" => "keep-alive", "cookie" => "_demo_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAACbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYME5oeGdhaHF6eXFKSUhXSXI4TEtBNkNVbQAAAA9jdXJyZW50X3VzZXJfaWRtAAAAJDMzYWZiYWFmLWE0YjYtNDQ0NS05M2NkLWJiZDkzMWExMzI2ZQ.CDek9yOjbjBOnr_UyIb2YkEbJzt8GaThoRRmwAVOS50", "host" => "localhost:4000", "upgrade-insecure-requests" => "1", ...}, host: "localhost", method: "GET", path: "/", peer: {{127, 0, ...}, 55044}, pid: #PID<0.816.0>, port: 4000, qs: "", ...}, "200 OK", %{"cache-control" => "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "content-length" => "2142", "content-type" => "text/html; charset=utf-8", "cross-origin-window-policy" => "deny", "date" => "Sat, 07 Nov 2020 08:18:59 GMT", "server" => "Cowboy", "set-cookie" => ["_demo_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAACbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYR2ZLcnEtaUtiR0xVSUlEWnViZTNxTllBbQAAAA9jdXJyZW50X3VzZXJfaWRtAAAAJDMzYWZiYWFmLWE0YjYtNDQ0NS05M2NkLWJiZDkzMWExMzI2ZQ.PaaEneIk1STc430uXlUm3ItoBnBnp5fdkQFaTr4gILc; path=/; HttpOnly"], "x-content-type-options" => "nosniff", "x-download-options" => "noopen", ...}, DemoWeb.Endpoint.HTTP, -576459137946131486, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, -576459137573558785, -576459137573558785, %{#PID<0.817.0> => %{...}}, [], ...}}, "GET", :"HTTP/1.1", :undefined, :undefined, 0, []}], [{:child, #PID<0.817.0>, 1, 5000, :undefined}]}, 1, [{:response, "200 OK", %{"cache-control" => "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "content-length" => "2142", "content-type" => "text/html; charset=utf-8", "cross-origin-window-policy" => "deny", "date" => "Sat, 07 Nov 2020 08:18:59 GMT", "server" => "Cowboy", "set-cookie" => ["_demo_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAACbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYR2ZLcnEtaUtiR0xVSUlEWnViZTNxTllBbQAAAA9jdXJyZW50X3VzZXJfaWRtAAAAJDMzYWZiYWFmLWE0YjYtNDQ0NS05M2NkLWJiZDkzMWExMzI2ZQ.PaaEneIk1STc430uXlUm3ItoBnBnp5fdkQFaTr4gILc; path=/; HttpOnly"], "x-content-type-options" => "nosniff", "x-download-options" => "noopen", "x-frame-options" => "SAMEORIGIN", "x-permitted-cross-domain-policies" => "none", "x-request-id" => "FkUr7USdNzJbU4YAAA0h", "x-xss-protection" => "1; mode=block"}, ["<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\"/>\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"/>\n    <title>Demo App</title>\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/css/app.css\"/>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\" content=\"FhZ4IAh7KhErdCFlPjwRNypQDEozCy95Qp3RyVCZI3m0wuUm_2iyBEv8\" csrf-param=\"_csrf_token\" method-param=\"_method\" name=\"csrf-token\">\n    <script defer type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/app.js\"></script>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <header>\n      <section class=\"container\">\n        <nav role=\"navigation\">\n          <ul>\n\n              <li>\n\n<a href=\"/login\">Login</a>\n\n              </li>\n\n          </ul>\n        </nav>\n        <a href=\"/\" class=\"phx-logo\">\n          Demo\n        </a>\n     </section>\n    </header>\n    <main role=\"main\" class=\"container\">\n<p class=\"alert alert-info\" role=\"alert\"></p>\n<p class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"></p>\n<section class=\"phx-hero\">\n  <h1>Welcome to Phoenix!</h1>\n  <p>Peace of mind from prototype to production</p>\n</section>\n\n<section class=\"row\">\n  <article class=\"column\">\n    <h2>Resources</h2>\n    <ul>\n      <li>\n        <a href=\"https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/overview.html\">Guides &amp; Docs</a>\n      </li>\n      <li>\n        <a href=\"https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix\">Source</a>\n      </li>\n      <li>\n        <a href=\"https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.5/CHANGELOG.md\">v1.5 Changelog</a>\n      </li>\n    </ul>\n  </article>\n  <article class=\"column\">\n    <h2>Help</h2>\n    <ul>\n      <li>\n        <a href=\"https://elixirforum.com/c/phoenix-forum\">Forum</a>\n      </li>\n      <li>\n        <a href=\"https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=elixir-lang\">#elixir-lang on Freenode IRC</a>\n      </li>\n      <li>\n        <a href=\"https://twitter.com/elixirphoenix\">Twitter @elixirphoenix</a>\n      </li>\n      <li>\n        <a href=\"https://elixir-slackin.herokuapp.com/\">Elixir on Slack</a>\n      </li>\n    </ul>\n  </article>\n</section>\n\n    </main>\n  ", "<iframe src=\"/phoenix/live_reload/frame\" style=\"display: none;\"></iframe>", "</body>", "\n</html>\n"]}]], [file: '/home/nayminlwin/Lab/phoenix/demo/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_http.erl', line: 954]}, {:cowboy_http, :loop, 1, [file: '/home/nayminlwin/Lab/phoenix/demo/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_http.erl', line: 254]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}`

I've stared at it for a long time and have no idea what to make of it. When I cleared the cookies, the site continues to work as expected.

Can anyone help explain what's going on? May be the expired session cookie's somehow causing this? If so, how should it be cleared properly?

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Not sure what type of authentication you are using, however I have a feeling that the redirect to `/` is the default behavior on session expiration. It loops infinitely most probably because your `/` path is also using the authentication plug, checking every time for a valid session.

Comment: Okay, stupid me..
I was keeping the `/` path in the router scope with the plug **where only guest users are allowed.** And the plug in that scope is redirecting back to `/` if the user is logged in, resulting in infinite redirect.
Was too focused on the error message to see what's happening.
I was following a tutorial I find online.
Thanks for the answer.